# callback function moved to an external js, does not work

Tags: node.js, express

I had an callback function on my router, and was working well, but like I wanted does not repeat my callback function to manage sql errors in one function, then i moved to external file

before move my callback function to an external file:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var model= require('../models/customers');

router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.header('content-type', 'application/json');

    console.log('will do model.get');

    model.get(function (err, rows) {

      if (err) {
        res.status(500).send({error: 'Something failed!'})
      } else {
        res.json({data: rows});
      }

    });
});
```

the response when there is error is ok:

```
{
    "error": "Something failed!"
}
```

after, i moved callback function to an  external file:

./lib/dbfunctions

```
var dbfunctions  = {
    runSql: function (err, rows) {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).send({error: 'Something failed!'})
        }
        else {
            res.json({data: rows});
        }
    }
}
module.exports = dbfunctions ;
```

and then i export this function in my file

router js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var model= require('../models/customers');
var dbfunctions = require('../libs/dbfunctions');

router.get('/:id?', function (req, res, next) {
    res.header('content-type', 'application/json');

    if (req.params.id) {

        model.getById(req.params.id, function (err, rows) {
            if (err) {

                res.json(err);
            }
            else {
                res.json({data:rows});
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        console.log('will do model.get');
        model.get( dbfunctions.runSql);
    }
});
```

but now the code is not working i got

```
ReferenceError: res is not defined
```

someone can explain me what is doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you moved the db callback handler to dbFunctions the call back now doesn't have closure over the router middleware function and as a result doesn't have `res` and `req`objects defined.

One way to fix it is to pass them in manually

```
var dbfunctions  = {
    runSql: function (err, rows, req, res) {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).send({error: 'Something failed!'})
        }
        else {
            res.json({data: rows});
        }
    }
}
module.exports = dbfunctions ;
```

router.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var model= require('../models/customers');
var dbfunctions = require('../libs/dbfunctions');

router.get('/:id?', function (req, res, next) {
    res.header('content-type', 'application/json');

    if (req.params.id) {

        model.getById(req.params.id, function (err, rows) {
            if (err) {

                res.json(err);
            }
            else {
                res.json({data:rows});
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        console.log('will do model.get');
        model.get(function(err,rows){
                dbfunctions.runSql(err, rows, req, res);
        });
    }
});
```